# Ubuntu 12.10 over Ubuntu 11.10 seems to hang

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, 12.10, 32-bit

My installation of Ubuntu 12.10 over Ubuntu 11.10 seems to hang on "saving installed packages". How long should I wait before knowing for sure that something is wrong? I stopped it once and tried re-installing but am getting the same results. I'm installing from a USB stick.

I'm connected to the internet using a wired connection but I'm reading [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest) to connect to a wi-fi network while installing. Could this possibly be the issue? I can't install using wi-fi at the moment as my router was fried in a brownout yesterday. I've ordered another router online so as soon as it gets in, I'll try again.

Any suggestions are appreciated! Please let me know if you need more information. It's a 32-bit installation and I have 1 GB of memory.

Thanks!

Comment: The WiFi issue is probably a '*Red Herring*' (distraction). Ethernet is usually foolproof, but WiFi may work fine.

Answer (score 0):

While you can *upgrade directly* from **10.04 LTS** to **12.10 LTS**, *that is the exception*.

---

Any other **Ubuntu** upgrade must be to the **next** release, so for **11.10** you need to first upgrade to **12.04 LTS**.

*Any other approach is untested, unsupported, and **not** recommended ..*